# Rails mailer test not interpreting URL helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a password resets mailer and I'd like to be able to do the following in my tests:

```
assert_match edit_password_reset_path(user.password_reset_token), mail.body.encoded
# undefined method `edit_password_reset_path' for #<UserMailerTest:0xb6c2ea0>
```

But it blows up because of the URL helper, so I have to do this instead to make my test run:

```
assert_match "\/password_resets\/#{user.password_reset_token}\/edit", mail.body.encoded
```

Which works fine, but don't look, or feel, so good.

It seems that ActionMailer::TestCase doesn't know about the path because the following fails:

```
assert_match "#{edit_password_reset_path(user.password_reset_token)}", mail.body.encoded
# undefined method `edit_password_reset_path' for #<UserMailerTest:0xb6c2ec8>
```

How do you access URL helpers like `edit_password_reset_path(user.password_reset_token)` in test-unit?

I'm switching over from RSpec where this was never an issue, the helpers just worked and I'd do this:

```
it "sends the user a password reset url" do
  mail.body.encoded.should match(edit_password_reset_url(user.password_reset_token))
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who is interested in solving this in the future, you can stick this in your test file:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

I don't know if this is *thee* way to do this, and I'm not sure how much overhead it adds to your tests, but it works ok.

Comment: This worked great in rails 3.2, but in rails 4 it causes a "ActionView::Template::Error: arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation" error [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660604/using-the-correct-url-for-method-in-a-rails-engine-spec)