# Using the correct url_for method in a Rails engine spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I have a request spec in a Rails engine. The view that is rendered calls a route and passes in a hash, i.e. `projects_path(:scope => "user")`. A route like this will eventually call `url_for`, but `url_for` is defined in many places. When running the application or running a request spec in the main app (root level), the call chain ends up at `ActionView::RoutingUrlFor#url_for`; when running a spec in the engine, however, the call chain ends up at `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper#url_for`.

In Rails 4, the `url_for` method defined in `UrlHelper` no longer accepts hash arguments, so I'm left with this error

```
 Failure/Error: visit projects_opportunity_intakes_path
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation
```

What I'm trying to figure out is why the heck it's falling back on `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` when I run a spec in my engine, but not in any other case. This is quite perplexing. One thing that stands out to me: when I put a breakpoint in my view and evaluate `self.class`, I *normally* get something that inherits from `ActionView::Base`, but when I run a spec from my engine, the class doesn't inherit from anything. I don't know if that's related, but it seems fishy.

Anyone experience this? Know a way around it? Could my modules be getting included in the wrong order? Is there something in `spec_helper` or in the dummy app initialization that I can do to make sure that the right modules are being used?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue when updating to Rails 4, and I discovered that the problem was a model containing the following line:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Try finding code in your application that includes `url_helpers` somewhere. Removing that line should help solve the problem.

Comment: The closest thing I have to that is `include MyEngine::Engine.routes.url_helpers` in my acceptance_helper.rb, and removing this leaves me with no access to my engine's routes.

Comment: thanks - helped me fix the issue in an integration test using capybara and named routes

Comment: Yeah, you saved my life... I was including this line in some rake task and all my test were failing.. remove the line and it works. The error message was quite confusing, as it was urging me to include that line instead of removing it :/

Comment: i had a case where url_helpers was included in a model, and it only broke when running in production mode. development mode worked fine o.O. thanks a ton for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. I had a model spec that included `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`and some of my tests from a different controller spec started failing with this same strange error message. Removing the line `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`from the spec solved the issue, but I was not able to figure out exactly what was happening. It was not necessary to remove this line from the model itself though. Observation: I'm using rails 4.1.1 and rspec-rails 3.0.2

Comment: Same problem here. Changed from using the `include` and `example_path` to using `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.example_path` fixed my problems.

Comment: Thanks! Same problem, we had this line in a mailer. Removing it fixed it. The bug only appeared on production though.

Comment: Funny story, I ran into this same issue a year later on a separate project that someone else had worked on before me. Couldn't get ActiveAdmin to work in production because of a `url_for` issue. There was an `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` at the start of a file for a mailer instead of being inside the class...

Answer (score 8):

It looks to me like the problem is that `include ActionView::Helpers` and `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` conflict with each other.

I've found that if you put `ActionView::Helpers` first it doesn't raise the error. So change

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers     
include ActionView::Helpers
```

to

```
include ActionView::Helpers
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't know when I'll have the chance to try it.

Comment: Wow, replacing `include ActionView::Helpers` with `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in my ApplicationController just helped me solve a completely opaque bug... I was running out of ideas and googling everything. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper -> In my case, this was the line that i had to search and comment.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was caused by passing a hash as the second argument of a link_to line.

```
<%= link_to('click me', {one: params[:one], two: params[:two]}) %>
```

wrapping the hash in the actual path method for the page fixed the issue

```
<%= link_to('click me', actual_path({one: params[:one], two: params[:two]})) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone scrolls this far...

Including `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` inside a class will prevent your tests from failing.

So change

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

class SomeClass
  # methods
end
```

into

```
class SomeClass
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  # methods
end
```