# Rails 4: respond_with arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my rails app (v. 4.1.9) i get the following error after a create action:

`arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation`

Here is my code:

**routes.rb**

```
scope module: :explore do
  resources :questions
end
```

**questions_controller.rb**

```
class Explore::QuestionsController < Explore::BaseController
  respond_to :html
  authorize_resource

  def create
    @question = Question.new question_params
    @question.save

    respond_with @question
  end
end
```

I also tried `respond_with question_path`and `redirect_to question_path` but always the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: try this `redirect_to questions_path`

Comment: Again the same error

Comment: where you want user to redirect, when question is created?

Comment: after creating I want to redirect to the show view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. In a helper I included `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper`. After removing this, `respond_with` and `redirect_to` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def create
    @question = Question.new question_params
    if @question.save
        flash[:success] = "Question created!"
        redirect_to questions_path
        or 
        redirect_to :controller => 'questions', :action => 'new'
        or
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

Comment: The same error: `arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation`

Comment: This is the error with Rails 4, try finding this line of code in your application `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` and commenting it as specifed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660604/using-the-correct-url-for-method-in-a-rails-engine-spec

Comment: I comment out all included `url_helpers` but thats not the solution